# Unable to get KVM guest console

Tags: centos, virtual-machine, kvm, console

I'm facing this issue in getting the console of a KVM guest while installing. My host(base) machine is CENTOS7, and the guest OS is also CENTOS7.

I dont have GUI on Host machine

```
# virt-install  --network bridge=br0 --name=node1 --ram=2048 \
   --vcpus=2 --disk path=/vm-images/node1.img,size=10 --graphics none \
   --location /tmp/CentOS-7-x86_64-Minimal-1611.iso --os-type=linux \
   --os-variant=rhel7.0 \
   --extra-args="console=tty0 console=ttyS0,115200n8 serial"
```

Error:

```
Starting install...
Retrieving file .treeinfo...          |  366 B  00:00:00
Retrieving file vmlinuz...            | 5.1 MB  00:00:00
Retrieving file initrd.img...         |  41 MB  00:00:00
Creating domain...                    |    0 B  00:00:00
Connected to domain node1
Escape character is ^]
```

Comment: do you get a login prompt (from the VM) if you hit enter at that point?  or does it just return to the shell on your host machine?

Comment: I don't even get the installation page ,, ineed to get text console for is installation1st

Comment: very odd.  that worked for me (all i had to changed was the path of the disk image and the location of the centos iso).   saw the kernel booting up and i'm now at the Installation menu.   Is this your first VM on this host? i.e. has it worked in the past?

Comment: Its 1st guest creation!  I'm having no luck in getting the os installation screen....